# Can't reinstall windows from usb/dvd

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I've got an Acer Aspire v5 551 (from a friend) and I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 (or any other Windows), because Windows crashed and didn't start anymore.

I already tried a lot of different ways to install windows:

- tried to install Windows 7 instead of Windows 10
- tried to install from windows dvd
- secure boot off/on
- legacy mode on/off
- 3 different usb sticks (USB 2.0 / USB 3.0)
- different tools to create a bootable usb stick (rufus, Microsoft Media Creation Tool, shell,Windows 7 USB/DVD tool)
- usb stick in fat32 and also ntfs
- partitioning of usb stick in mbr/gpt

and yes, the boot order is correct. DVD/usb are first in the order.

As you see, I tried a lot of different things. But it is just loading the dvd/usb and I see for a few minutes the loading bar, but never the windows setup starts. The only success I could achieve is to start a live ubuntu from usb, which worked without any trouble.

If you have any other idea, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I placed the hdd in my pc and tried to install windows. If I use my usual hdd the setup starts, with the laptop hdd the same as on the laptop, just a black screen after a while.

I placed both hdds in my computer and chkdsk tried to fix the hdd, but without success. There are already too many bad sectors. Therefore the hdd is broken.

Maybe this helps someone in the future.